# Simplify $W(xa^x)$

Tags: lambert-w

I'm not sure if there is any way to simplify $W(xa^x)$.  It's pretty clear that $a=e$ simplifies to $x$ or $W_k(xe^x)$, but any other value of $a$, other than trivial values like $a=0,1$, don't seem simplifyable.

[Here is a graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/yitderkwmi) you may want to view.  It appears to be asymptotic to a linear function is the most I can observe.

From the graph, I observed

> $$W(xa^x)\sim\ln(a)x$$

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer, though I'd really like to see one:

Well, $xa^x=xe^{x \ln(a)}$.

Consequently, if you define: $y=xe^{x \ln(a)}$, it is well defined that:

$x \ln(a)=W(y\ln(a))$

And  I'm not sure if that is any more helpful. I'll definitely research a bit more though.

Comment: Thanks for the effort.  I did manage to get what you did in my own attempt, but then it hit me that it wasn't actually helpful, at least in any way I could see.  :(